# Copy files to server from google docs example?

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-api

I have looked for a while and am trying to find out if it is possible to copy files to and from google docs to your own server.

If so, does anyone have a example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Google Drive API to [download](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) and [upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads) files from/to Google Drive.

For more details, please check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/